# Program Error: Debugging on a remote computer having NO VS installed using temviewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, clickonce, remote-debugging

I have a clickone deployment on one of my friends system. The application works just fine on my system, however it has some issues running on his system.

I was going through the application installed on his PC using Teamviewer. I was wondering is that possible to debug the application on my friends PC without installing Visual studio on his computer. Just debugging, to find out the issue.

I have already tried out the `WinDbg` but its sought of very typical and i'll take days to find the issue.

Is there any other alternate you people can guide me with.

**Also i want to share the error i am getting:**

On my system the datas are properly saved in the database, but on his system it says `there are less fields than input values`

So for this issue i just wanted to see the problem area, because i have more than 10 Insert commands running at a time on click. SO which one is creating problem i want to find out.

Comment: How about to just add logging? Put in log what info and where is being saved to, and you'll find your problem. Probably, problem is in way of DB file creation. Try to clean all your program's info and make it build full DB structure or run a virtual OS on your desktop and run your app there.

Comment: @Hikiko Ok, so could you please guide me on how to activate the logging stuff. Maybe you can provide any startup link from where i can start learning. I am also googling meanwhile

Comment: @Hikiko Actually its a rebuild application deployment. So we can skipp this step :)

Comment: I mean add logging functionality into your app. In the place where SQL commands are being called.